# How to pass data to layouts in Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

i have a problem. So idea is here:

I have a collection (data from table - Navbar menu items and sub-menu items), and i need to pass it to my layout page, because navbar in my case is in header part. I created dynamic navbar while it was in actual main index page, but when i finished it and wated to move it to layout page, nothing works. Below is my code

Livewire Dashboard class

```
class Dashboard extends Component
{
    public $categories;

    public function render()
    {
      abort_unless(auth()->user()->can('view_dashboard'), 403);

      return view('livewire.admin.dashboard');
    }

    public function mount()
    {
      $this->categories = \App\Models\Navigation::with('children')->where('parent_id','=',0)->get();
    }
}
```

It passes all data from table to dashboard page, but my navbar it not there.

The NavBar is located in `layouts.navigation` page

The part code of `layouts.app` page:

```
@auth
            <!-- regular sidebar -->
            <div class="sidebar hidden flex-none w-full md:block md:w-60 px-4 bg-primary dark:bg-gray-700">
                @include('layouts.navigation')
            </div>
@endauth
```

So how can i send data to `layouts.navigation` page, from `Dashboard Controller`, cuz i use that controller in my route

Comment: I feel like some parts are missing in your question, but to go step by step: in livewire.admin.dashboard view, you can access your public $categories variable from Livewire component as $this->categories. Secondly instead of populating categories on mount, I'd suggest you populate it as a property, since mount only runs once, but properties are on demand.